# Creating a 20 second timer doesn't work and I'm trying to understand why

Tags: javascript, html, css, timer, countdown

I've been trying to implement [the following code](https://www.shecodes.io/athena/52336-how-to-create-a-countdown-timer-in-javascript) into my website:

```
let count = 20;
const timer = setInterval(function() {
  count--;
  console.log(count);
  if (count === 0) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    console.log("Time's up!");
  }
}, 1000);
```

`<p>Your time is running out... <span id="timer"></span> sec</p>`

I got this span I want to insert the countdown into and I've been trying many options of which none worked. I'm quite new to JavaScript so appreciate a hint on what I am doing wrong.

Amongst other things I tried the following but nothing really happened..

```
function startTimer () {
  let count = 20;
const timer = setInterval(function() {
  count--;
  console.log(count);
  if (count === 0) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    console.log("Time's up!");
  }
}, 1000);
  let countdown = document.getElementById("timer").innerContent;
  count = countdown;
  console.log(countdown);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have some suggestion

### Don't reassign `count`

The code below will change your `count` to something weird and it will break your timer

```js
count = countdown;
```

`count` is a number from 20 to 0. You use it to countdown, so let it be

### Call your method

I don't know if you've called `startTimer` or not. But make sure you call it

### Change the way to assign `innerContent`

First, you should use `innerText` instead

Second, you should change your code from

```js
let countdown = document.getElementById("timer").innerContent;
count = countdown;
```

To this

```js
let countdown = document.getElementById("timer");
countdown = count;
```

This will fix your first problem and set 20 to any tag with `id="timer"`
. Only assign `document.getElementById("timer")` to `countdown` (not `document.getElementById("timer").innerText`) because it's an object. So it can be pass by reference

### Display timer

Now, you can display countdown value on screen with few adjustment

```js
function startTimer() {
  let count = 20;
  let countdown = document.getElementById("timer");
  const timer = setInterval(function () {
    count--;
    console.log(count);
    countdown.innerText = count;
    if (count === 0) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      console.log("Time's up!");
    }
  }, 1000);
}

startTimer();
```

Everytime `count` change, replace `countdown.innerText` with `count`'s value

Hope this help

Comment: Hi there! :)
Thank you for your advice so far.
Unfortunately, it still does not work 

Comment: Why not? What's the problem? It working here https://codepen.io/duckstery/pen/LYqyqxZ

Comment: Ok, I found the problem and now it is working!
It didn't have anything to do with your suggested code.
Thank you!!